# Conditional expression in XSLT

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to pass a value to an attribute that based on a condition whether some value is empty or not. If not, an attribute should get this value, if yes, it gets another one.

Currently, I pass these value just in line assuming I get only one of them. For example,

```
<xsl:template match="/test">
    <Settings Checksum="{//test/metadata[@name='parChecksum']/@data}
        {//test/metadata[@name='root']/metadata[@name='parChecksum']/@data}" />
</xsl:template>
```

Input XML could be like this:

```
<test>
    <metadata name="root">
        <metadata name="parChecksum" data="90eee2"/>
    </metadata>
</test>
```

or this:

```
<test>
    <metadata name="parChecksum" data="e6f963"/>
</test>
```

I want to have an expression that selects only one of them, because in case of having both values an attribute will get an erroneus value.

Comment: Provide input XML too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath 2.0 and later have an `if (conditionExpression) then expression1 else expression2` expression. It is also possible to create a sequence `(expression1, expression2)` but only to select the first item `(expression1, expression2)[1]`, in that case if `expression1` evaluates to a non-empty item, it is selected, if it evaluates to an empty sequence, the result of `expression2` is used.

Comment: Thanks! The second one worked: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWBy/1 It looks better since no need to calculate value twice